# AngularJS - Factory.function(...) is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want to start off by saying I am very new to AngularJS so any help would be appreciated!

I am trying to collect some JSON data from a URL in a factory function and then return the data to the controller, but it throws an error saying that the function doesn't exist. I have been following along with a tutorial series on Udemy, but the data I am collecting is coming from a different source so the answer isn't in the videos.

Code:

```
angular.module('MainModule', ['ngRoute']);
angular.module('MainModule').config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/index.html'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/item/:id', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/item.html',
    });
});
angular.module('MainModule').controller('ItemsController', function($scope, ItemsFactory, MainSettings){
    ItemsFactory.getItems().then(function(response){
        $scope.items = response;
    });
    $scope.settings = MainSettings;
});
angular.module('MainModule').controller('ItemController', function($scope, $routeParams, ItemsFactory, MainSettings){
    $scope.item = ItemsFactory.getItem($routeParams.id);
    $scope.settings = MainSettings;
});
angular.module('MainModule').factory('ItemsFactory', function($http, $log){
    var factory = {};
    var items = false;
    factory.getItems = function(){
        $http.get('/index.php').success(function(response){
            items = response.items;
            return items;
        });
    };
    factory.getItem = function(item){
        var i = 0;
        while (i < items.length) {
            if (items[i].id == item) {
                return items[i];
            }
            i++;
        }
        return false;
    };
    return factory;
});
angular.module('MainModule').constant('MainSettings', {
    title: 'Simple RSS Reader',
    version: '1.0'
});
```

Error:

```
Error: ItemsFactory.getItems(...) is undefined
@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular-module.js:11:2
invoke@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular.js:3965:14
instantiate@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular.js:3976:23
$ControllerProvider/this.$get</<@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular.js:7307:18
nodeLinkFn/<@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular.js:6696:34
forEach@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular.js:332:11
nodeLinkFn@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular.js:6683:11
compositeLinkFn@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular.js:6131:13
publicLinkFn@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular.js:6027:30
ngViewFillContentFactory/<.link@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular-route.js:915:7
nodeLinkFn@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular.js:6737:13
compositeLinkFn@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular.js:6131:13
publicLinkFn@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular.js:6027:30
createBoundTranscludeFn/boundTranscludeFn@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular.js:6151:21
controllersBoundTransclude@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular.js:6758:18
update@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular-route.js:865:25
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$broadcast@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular.js:13070:15
updateRoute/<@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular-route.js:547:15
qFactory/defer/deferred.promise.then/wrappedCallback@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular.js:11659:31
qFactory/defer/deferred.promise.then/wrappedCallback@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular.js:11659:31
qFactory/ref/<.then/<@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular.js:11745:26
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular.js:12788:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular.js:12600:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular.js:12892:13
done@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular.js:8427:34
completeRequest@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular.js:8641:7
createHttpBackend/</xhr.onreadystatechange@http://192.168.1.234:1000/js/angular.js:8580:1

<div class="ng-scope" ng-view="">
```

Thanks in advance, Matt!

Comment: your function `factory.getItems` don't return anything, you need just return your _$http_ like `factory.getItems = function(){
        return $http.get('/index.php').success(function(response){
            items = response.items;
            return items;
        });
    };`

Answer (score 0):

My issue was similar to this and I resolved it by injecting my Factory like so -

```
angular.module('MainModule').controller('ItemsController', ['ItemsFactory', function($scope, ItemsFactory, MainSettings){
    ItemsFactory.getItems()
    .success(function(response) {..})
    .error(function(response) {..})
    .then(function(response){
        $scope.items = response;
    });
    $scope.settings = MainSettings;
}]);
```

You would to eventually do this if you decide to use a minification library or RequireJS. More information [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Both fixes, separately and together remove the error, but the data still isn't returned. Does the order that the injections are listed in the controller make any difference to the way they work?

Comment: you can update your post instead adding answer that not answer. also what you mean _but the data still isn't returned_?

Comment: The error has been removed, but the JSON data that I am expecting to be returned still isn't available in the controller.

Comment: update you post with your changes. do you try debug it?

Comment: Did you try to confirm whether the $http request is getting the right result? Can you log the return from it?

Comment: Yes, the $http request returns the correct data within the factory when I log it, it just isn't returned when the function is called within the controller.

Comment: Thats understandable since you are not returning the $http object itself.Return the $http and handle the callbacks from your controller. Please see updated code in my answer. There are other ways to do this using promises (which is the best practice).